# Method lock in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have one class with these three methods. This class is used by many threads.
I would like the Method1 to wait, if Method2 and/or Method3 are running in any threads.
Any suggestions?

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void Method1() 
    {
        Object lockThis = new Object();

        lock (lockThis)
        {
            //Body function
        }
    }

    public static void Method2() 
    {
         //Body function
    }

    public static void Method3() 
    {
         //Body function
    }
}
```

Comment: Method2 and Method3 can execute simultaneous? The and/or implies that in some way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need something like this:

```
static object lockMethod2 = new object();
static object lockMethod3 = new object();

public static void Method1() 
{
    lock (lockMethod2)
    lock (lockMethod3)
    {
        //Body function
    }
}

public static void Method2() 
{
    lock (lockMethod2)
    {
        //Body function
    }
}

public static void Method3() 
{
    lock (lockMethod3)
    {
        //Body function
    }
}
```

This allows method3 to execute if method2 is running and vice versa, while method1 must wait for both. Of course, method2 and 3 will not run while 1 is running.

Comment: What if Method1 is running parallel? And you need all the threads to access method1?

Answer (score 14):

The current implementation of your lock is completely useless, because every thread will lock on a different object.
Locking is usually done with a readonly field that is initialized only once.
Like this, you can easily lock multiple methods:

```
public class Class1
{
    private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

    public static void Method1() 
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            //Body function
        }
    }

    public static void Method2() 
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            //Body function
        }
    }

    public static void Method3() 
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            //Body function
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx)

Similar to read operations, Method 2 and Method3 may occur in parallel, while Method1 (like a write operation) would need to wait for those to finish. 
It's not the regular read/write concurrency situation, but the logic is similar.

```
public class Class1
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim methodLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    public static void Method1() 
    {
        methodLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            //Body function
        }
        finally
        {
            methodLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public static void Method2() 
    {
         methodLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            //Body function
        }
        finally
        {
            methodLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public static void Method3() 
    {
         methodLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            //Body function
        }
        finally
        {
            methodLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are multi-threading then the `lock` has to be accessible to all threads.  Therefore, in this case, your locks needs to be static for the static methods to see it.

Your current setup will make a new lock object for each thread.  Therefore, providing now synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your requirement correctly then you can do it like this:

```
public static object lockobj = new object();
public static void Method1() 
{
    
    lock (lockobj)
    {
        // Body of Method1

        // Call Method2
        Method2();

        // Call Method3
        Method3();

        // More code in Method1
    }
}

public static void Method2() 
{  
    //Body function   
}

public static void Method3() 
{ 
    //Body function    
}
```

Comment: Your answer isn't clear. As this is your first answer please read the HowToAnswer section https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Anyway there are 3 good answers, 1 is accepted, so your answer really doesn't add value at the moment.