# How to lock a method so that this method can't be called simultaneously in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, locking

I have a method called `GetAuthCode()`. It is used to get an authorization code from an API server for my web server. I then store this code in the cache.

Because there is an expire time of this authorization code. So when it is expired, I'll call `GetAuthCode()` again.

---

Question:

If there comes 10 request 'simultaneously'(considering network deny)  and the code has been expired, each request will call `GetAuthCode()`.

Under this circumstance, I only want the very first request to `successfully` call `GetAuthCode()`. So I want to 'lock' this method:

`When GetAuthCode() has been called, it can't be called by others at that moment`

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14977247/795683

Comment: I only want to call `GetAuthCode( )` once at this momont,  this solution can not help. It will call 10 times in order eventually.

Comment: you can set a flag first time and you can check that flag value  before execute the function.

Comment: `public void test(ref bool occupied)
        {
            occupied = true;
            methodLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                // do sth.
            }
            finally
            {
                occupied = false;
                methodLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
            
        }`    Didn't work, somewhere wrong?

Comment: can you add your complete code to question to understand.